# problem with SurfaceView callback

Tags: android

My code includes a class Preview which extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceHolder.Callback.   After the user configures a wake up time in the launch activity an alarm is set. The user then uses the back key to exit the app and return to the device home screen  When the alarm is received an intent is called and an activity started to create the SurfaceView.    If I set the alarm to 10 minutes say and the device screen timeout is 15 minutes all proceeds correctly.   However if I set the alarm to 20 minutes with screen timeout at 10 minutes then the alarm is received, the SurfaceView class is created and the Holder and Holder.Callback is set but the callback item surfaceCreated is never reached.   I have inserted calls in the code to write tracing out to a file so that I know where is stopped functioning.

Am I missing some implication of the app waking up after the screen

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having a similar problem like I had here: [Game crashing when device's password screen enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637688/game-crashing-when-devices-password-screen-enabled)

The sequence of events is not as usual in a SurfaceView instance when coming back from sleep, therefore you would have to write a code to handle such situations.